# HTTPS to HTTP redirect Apache2

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, redirect

The following is having no effect on the URL.  I want to redirect anyone who requests using HTTPS://  to a normal HTTP:// URL  Its seem this should be very simple, but its eating up a bunch of time...  Can anyone help.

```
#Redirect your Homepage from HTTPS to HTTP
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Where are you putting this, a .htaccess file?

Comment: No httpd.conf  its a rack application ruby / sinatra

Comment: Which section is this in, is it inside a `VirtualHost`? You have restarted the web server after each change?